# Minimize in view code

Tags: vb.net, minimize

With the `#Region #End Region` you can Minimize the information to take less room and organize it.

The question that I have is with in the `Private Sub` can you do the same thing?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjeoe.png]

If you look at the Picture up above, were you see `Text to speech`has + symbol next to it, I want to do the same thing but with in the Private Sub to help organize everything.

Comment: You cannot have collapsible regions inside a Sub.

Comment: some would argue that if you have so much code in one sub that you need Regions, that you need to break it up into smaller procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s.aspx)). Just highlight the block of text you want to be collapsible and select:

**"Outlining --> Hide Selection"**

[image]

Then the selected block will collapse and give you [+] sign to expand/collapse it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since we are not able to make collapsible regions within a Sub, you can make other Subs/Functions that you can call inside of the outer Sub. This would give a minimized look.

Add Summary Comments to these methods and they will help you remember what they do and what the parameters mean - if needed. [Further Reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx).

```
''' <summary>
''' What this method does!
''' </summary>
Private Sub DoSomething()
  'TODO: add code here
End Sub
```